# Как перенаправиться на ту страницу в которой находишься router.push Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Есть у меня функциональность, которая просто сбрасывает проект в начальное состояние и мне нужно перенаправиться на ту же самую страницу, в которой находишься

**this.$router.push({name: this.$router.name, query: {}}**) --> не работает

В данном случае я подразумевал, что пустой объект как бы задаст уникальность адресу и не будет ошибки

**Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/".**

В русоанглоинтернете ничего не нашел, идей нету, как реализовать такую штуку (по идее обычный редирект на ту же самую страницу)

Comment: А если попробовать `push` заменить `replace`'ом?

Comment: @smellyshovel router.replace({}) не решает проблему
В шаблоне router link :to="/" делает как раз то, что мне нужно, но как эмулирвоать это поведение

Answer (score 1):

Редирект vue-router'ом на ту же самую страницу, чисто логически не имеет смысла. Потому что это (по принципу действия) загрузка того же самого компонента в vue-слот.

Вместо того чтобы искать пути обхода *правильного и ожидаемого* поведения vue-router'а - следует ввести вспомогательный метод для "сброса" состояния компонента/приложения в исходное или пустое состояние, и вместо редиректа переиспользовать метод везде где такой сброс требуется.
То есть: вместо того чтобы костылить код ради допущенной ошибки проектирования, лучше будет просто исправить эту ошибку (предусмотрев в логике приложения операцию "сброс"/"возврат", и тем самым исключив саму потребность в костыле с редиректом).

---

Общие пути корректного решения:

- для сброса глобального состояния (Vuex) - стейт инициализировать не литералом объекта, а функцей-фабрикой возвращающей объект стейта (и далее переиспользуем эту функцию в мутации устанавливающей все состояние целиком);
- для сброса локального состояния компонента - можно использовать как функцию-фабрику объекта `data` объявленную *вне* компонента (тот же принцип, что и в пункте выше), так и метод компонента явно присваивающий исходные значения полям локального состояния.

В сценарии клонирования начального состояния (вместо использования фабрики), сократить код копирования вложенных в состояние объектов поможет деструктуризация, или использование утилит типа `cloneDeep` (из lodash).

Comment: Это исходит от бэка. Любят они редиректы

Comment: @Дмытрык, я не понял, что именно зависит от бэка? При HTTP-переходе, страница веб-приложения будет полностью перезагружена (т.к. этот кейс не vue-router обрабатывает, а непосредственно браузер). Но судя по вопросу, ТСу хочется именно из кода вебприложения сделать редирект на тот же локейшн, **именно через vue-router** (т.е., переход не браузером, а повторной загрузкой того же самого компонента в `router-view`, что лишено практического смысла)...

Comment: Ну, у меня в приложении бэк, вместе с данными, присылает поле redirect, которое иногда может совпадать с текущим урлом. И мы, как-бы эмулируем редирект браузера, с помощью vue-routera.Т.е. полное перезагрузки не происходит.  Я понимаю, что правильнее обновить данные, но так уж получилось. Бэку проще прислвть редирект, чем собирать обновленные данные

Comment: @Дмытрык, согласен что проще. Но то что сервер присылает, это уже вопрос скорее пересылки данных... а вот в отношении "перезагрузки текущей страницы" через vue-router (сабжа вопроса), все же правильнее делать так как предусматривает эта библиотека и подход Vue в целом, а не костылить против них. Хорошая (рекомендуемая техн.стеком) практика всегда предпочтительнее хаков.

Comment: @yar85 Что значит "использование функции фабрики, возвращающей объект стейта?

Comment: @Xeros, ну, это значит то что написано: везде где нужен новый объект стейта, используем функцию-фабрику для его создания. Что именно в этом является непонятным?

Comment: @yar85 Я в терминологии "функция-фабрика" не уверен, можете дать статью или примерчик какой-то?

Comment: @Xeros, самая обычная терминология основ программирования. Фабрикой называется функция возвращающая объект, и при этом не являющаяся конструктором. https://www.sitepoint.com/factory-functions-javascript/

Comment: @Xeros, по факту, `data` в объекте vue-компонента является фабричным методом (только не класса, как в Java и подобных языках, а нетипизированного объекта объявленного литералом: объекта конфигурации компонента). Этот метод не попадет в методы vue-экземпляра. Поместив тот же код в самостоятельную функцию - мы декомпозируем объект конфигурации компонента, получая возможность переиспользования функции: не только в роли метода объекта-конфига (для инициализации внутренних свойств aka локального состояния) vue-экземпляра, но и в методах vue-экземпляра (для "сброса" состояния после инстанцирования).

Answer (score 0):

Невозможность сдеать редирект на ту же странуцу, происходит из-за того, что VUE не видит изменений.

Для решения подобной проблемы, я написал вот такой вот метод

```
function goToUrl(url) {
  if (url === location.pathname + location.search) {
    router.push({
      path: '/'
    });
  }
  router.push(url);
}
```

К сожалению, у него есть проблема, и заключается она в том, что сбивается история переходов.

Comment: не работает, по факту твой метод делает тоже самое, что и мой просто переводи на главную страницу.

Comment: router-link to='/' делает как раз то, что мне нужно, можно ли как-то эмулировать это поведение?